# NLP+Non Text Features . How to give more weight to non NLP features?

Tags: classification, nlp

I have some text and some metadata associated with it. Before classification I have made feature matrix in such way:

```
Non Text features + TFIDF vectorizer matrix
```

So if had 5 non text features (like position of text, does text contain digits etc) and TFIDF matrix contains 100 columns then total columns fed to classifier is 105. I am using DecisionTree classifier.

Now, the problem is that, the classifier is using only features derived from text to make decisions. In some cases of mis-classifications I observed that the non text feature (position of text) was actually the decision factor.

I think it is because the number of features generated by TFIDF vectorizer are too many (1800+). Any idea on how to make other features also contributor to classification.

In case you want to see code :

```
train_x =  train[["Diff","col9","col10", "col6"]]  # Non text features
tfidf_vect = TfidfVectorizer(analyzer='word', token_pattern=r'\w{1,}', use_idf=False, ngram_range=(1,3))
train_x1 = pd.concat([train_x, xtrain_tfidf_ngram_df], axis=1)  #Merge non text and text features
model.fit(train_x1, y=train_y)
predicted=model.predict(test_x1)
```

Sample training matrix after merge:

```
     index  Diff  col9  col10  col6    0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7  ...  1875  1876  1877  1878  1879  1880  1881  1882  1883  1884  1885  1886  
1887
0        0 -2158     1      1     0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  ...   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0  
 0.0
1        1    15     1      1     1  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  ...   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0  
 0.0
2        2    27     1      1     0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  ...   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0  
 0.0
```

Comment: If you have to many features, and this goes for every ML problem, your model can fit to noise. Remove some TFIDF features and see if that helps.

Comment: TFIDF features are auto generated based on number of words. I am wondering if my hand crafted features can get more importance?

Comment: You can do a feature selection for TFIDF. Either use the n most common n-grams, or use something such as f_classif. It's not recommended to use all ngrams

Comment: It's not recommended to use all ngrams - How to select which NGrams to use?

Comment: If you use sklearns tfidfvectorizer you can use the parameter max_features. It uses the most common way of selecting what ngrams to use. It should be easy for you to implement it yourself if you donøt use sklearn for generating TFIDF :)
Let me know if I should remake this to an actual answer.

Comment: Your suggestion of max_features sounds good. But I have played with max_feature in range of 100, 200 etc. and the accuracy of classifier has gone very down now. It becomes good when max_features >1000 . But in that case my handcrafted feature does not have any effect!!!

Comment: Of course your accuracy will go down if you go below a threshold on the number of tfidf features. A normal choice of tfidf features is between 5k-15k and dependent on your data.
Perhaps your handcrafted features are not informative, or your model not complex enough to pick them up? You could try an XGBoost model perhaps. You could also check feature importance